# Can't write mp4/m4a to file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, file, url, mp4

I'm trying to write an mp4/m4a to a file so I can edit it's metadata. It's not saving to the file though. I don't have a clue as to why it isn't saving and I've been trying to fix it for a long time now. The _previewData has data from a url (www.example.com/file.m4a), and it is retrieved successfully.

```
_previewData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a281.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/119/Music/v4/f1/7b/d6/f17b‌​d6e3-55c0-b7e0-9863-bc522900e950/mzaf_5153970109972844579.aac.m4a"]];
NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentDirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *path = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"file.mp4"]];
                NSFileManager *filemanager;
                filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                [_previewData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
                if ([filemanager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
                    // Runs
                    NSLog(@"It worked");
                }
                NSLog(@"%@",path);
```

With this new code, it saves it in a file and the above NSLog writes `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FF533DE5-1A07-44A9-A191-42F3301BB150/Documents/file.mp4`. I then edit the file using this code:

```
ANMovie* file = [[ANMovie alloc] initWithFile:path]; // or .mp4
                NSData* jpegCover = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(artworkImage, 1.0);
                _imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:jpegCover];
                ANMetadata* metadata = [[ANMetadata alloc] init];
                metadata.albumCover = [[ANMetadataImage alloc] initWithImageData:jpegCover type:ANMetadataImageTypeJPG];
                [file setMovieMetadata:metadata];
                [file close];

                _previewData = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

The mp4/m4a is empty though and can't successfully be copied and pasted somewhere.
This is the code used to copy the mp4 and other data:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
                NSDictionary *imageItem=@{@"public.mpeg-4-audio":self.previewData};
                NSDictionary *textItem=@{@"public.plain-text":self.linkData};

                pasteboard.items=@[imageItem,textItem];
```

Comment: Andy, I did. Last line of the code

Comment: you can not write data to mainBundle, you should know what's sandbox mean

Comment: junkor I've tried this as well `[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"file.mp4"]]` instead of NSBundle. Same result.

Comment: Not all of the code works perfectly. The mp4 is empty after retrieving it from the file

Comment: I added (the first line of code in question) the code to set _preview data. And the last few lines at the end are what I'm trying to do with the data.

Answer (score 0):

It must be something is wrong with your code,you can do it like this,and it works fine for me:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_0387" ofType:@"MOV"];
NSData *netData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSArray *paths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentPath = paths.firstObject;
NSString *savePath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp.MOV"];
[netData writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL saved = [manager fileExistsAtPath:savePath isDirectory:NULL];
if (saved) {
    NSLog(@"it's saved");
}
```

the 'IMG_0387.MOV'is a mov file in the mainBundle.

Comment: oh,yes.you should check the data not empty at first.

Comment: The data is not empty  until I set it back to `_previewdata`.